# DIV Background Refuses to Change Color or Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to change the background of this section of the page:

---

[image]

---

And I want to change it to a background image of space, I tried using CSS but it refuses to work. I have looked up many times but the only thing it likes to do is outline the div section rather then actually change the image inside, why?

Code HTML:

```
    <div class="section section-pad-sm section-bg section-pro into-section" id="intro">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-md-5 section-four-image">
                    <div class="video-graph res-m-btm animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".1">
                        <div class="header-image section-third-image header-image-alt">
                            <img src="images/header-image-blue-old.png" alt="header">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- .col  -->
                <div class="col-md-6 order-md-first order-last">
                    <div class="text-block">
                        <h6 class="heading-xs animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".0">What is Hashimo Shares? </h6>
                        <h2 class="animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".1">Hashimo Shares is a beautifully crafted
                            <br> Shared Masternode Service for Everyone! </h2>
```

And so fourth.

CSS:

```
#intro {
    background-color: blue;
    background: grey;
    color: blue;
}
```

I also tried:

```
#intro {
background-image: url('../images/header-shade.jpg');
background-repeat: repeat-y; /* for vertical repeat */
background-repeat: repeat-x; /* for horizontal repeat */
}
```

Neither worked, it stayed white. But trying to outline it using CSS made it work just fine, why?

**I also tried changing it with JS.**

Comment: Put more HTML in a snippet please.

Comment: Can you provide a live view

Comment: Have a look at the Computed Styles pane in the Chrome Dev tools (or equivalent) to track down which styles are applied, and why it's not what you expect: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/elements-styles#computed_style

Comment: Just to be clear, your background has an image and you want that image to be replaced with a blue background?

Comment: Please add some more html which wraps your white background area.

Comment: Can't help you unless you provide a working code. Try creating a fiddle/plunker or create a StackOverflow snippet.

Comment: I added more, but I Can't add a fiddle because it works in Fiddle?

Comment: If it works in fiddle then that should narrow down where the issue is. It's not what you've put in the fiddle. Use dev tools as already suggested where it is broken. An important technique in debugging is to reproduce the issue with as little code as possible, also known as a [MCVE]. We can only guess at the issue, until we see code that replicates the problem.

Comment: I don't know anything of what the issue will be, it's fine, I have someone else helping me still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to edit an image with code.

Solution 1: Images, i.e. that one, cannot be changed using a code. To change the image background color, you would just fill it in using a photo editor, then change the image when it is triggered.

Solution 2: If you deleted the background, possibly using [this](https://digiwonk.gadgethacks.com/how-to/quickest-easiest-way-remove-backgrounds-from-images-without-using-photoshop-0146999/) tutorial, and put *that* in a div, and filled the background of the div your color, then it probably would work.

the tutorial might be difficult, so if that doesn't work, you can look it up.

Edit: That was not what this person was looking for, I will put the solution.

To change the background color, in CSS,  add `body {backgrounds color: color;}`

In HTML, add in the `<html>` or `<body>` tag `bgcolor="hexadecimal"` where hexadecimal is the color you want in hexadecimal form.

Note: I would not recommend the second one.

Now of course if you wanted the background to change once an event happened, I would use jQuery `.css();` function

```js
$("#div").mouseenter(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "blue");
});
$("#div").mouseleave(function() {
  $("body").css("background-color", "white");
});
```

```css
#div {
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div"> Hello </div>
```

The events can be changed, and what happens can be changed. This was just an example.

To work with your code:

```js
var background = 0;
$("#button").click(function() {
  if (background == 0) {
  $("#intro").css("background-color", "blue");
    background = 1
  } else {
  $("#intro").css("background-color", "white");
  background = 0
  }
});
```

```css
#button {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button"></button>
<!-- Start Section -->
        <div class="section section-pad-sm section-bg section-pro into-section" id="intro">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-5 section-four-image">
                        <div class="video-graph res-m-btm animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".1">
                            <div class="header-image section-third-image header-image-alt">
                                <img src="images/header-image-blue-old.png" alt="header">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col  -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 order-md-first order-last">
                        <div class="text-block">
                            <h6 class="heading-xs animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".0">What is Hashimo Shares? </h6>
                            <h2 class="animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".1">Hashimo Shares is a beautifully crafted
                                <br> Shared Masternode Service for Everyone! </h2>
                            <p class="lead animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".2">Test </p>
                            <p class="animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".3">Test</p>
                            <p class="animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".4">Test</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col  -->
                </div>
                <!-- .row  -->
            </div>
            <!-- .conatiner  -->
        </div>
```

As you can see, I made it so that when you click the button, it makes the intro div's background go blue, and when clicked again it makes it white again.

Now, if you wish for it to be blue on startup, you could do this:

```js
$("#intro").css("background-color", "blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Start Section -->
        <div class="section section-pad-sm section-bg section-pro into-section" id="intro">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-md-5 section-four-image">
                        <div class="video-graph res-m-btm animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".1">
                            <div class="header-image section-third-image header-image-alt">
                                <img src="images/header-image-blue-old.png" alt="header">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col  -->
                    <div class="col-md-6 order-md-first order-last">
                        <div class="text-block">
                            <h6 class="heading-xs animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".0">What is Hashimo Shares? </h6>
                            <h2 class="animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".1">Hashimo Shares is a beautifully crafted
                                <br> Shared Masternode Service for Everyone! </h2>
                            <p class="lead animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".2">Test </p>
                            <p class="animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".3">Test</p>
                            <p class="animated" data-animate="fadeInUp" data-delay=".4">Test</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- .col  -->
                </div>
                <!-- .row  -->
            </div>
            <!-- .conatiner  -->
        </div>
```

I would not recommend that, but if it won't work with css, I guess you'll have to do with that.

Update: use `!important` at the end of the css block, because in your file 'style0ad1.css', it declared the class `section-pro` a color and made it prominent over any other declarations.

So to make it your space background: `background: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/af/0f/c4/af0fc46fa7f05330435e9e71779af666.jpg") !important`

Try it out!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170735/discussion-on-answer-by-random-channel-div-background-refuses-to-change-color-or).